# How to store that two clients are related?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-key-relationship

Assuming I have a simple `client` table with columns `id` and `name` filled with following rows:

```
ID | NAME
01 | John
02 | Mary
03 | Smith
04 | George
05 | Allan
```

I want to store at my database that *John* are friend of *Mary*, *Smith* and *Allan*.

How can I create a relational table to link this clients?

Currently, I use a table like:

```
CLIENT_A | CLIENT_B
   01    |    02
   01    |    03
   01    |    05
```

With an UNIQUE(client_a, client_b)

But this also allows that I have an repeated relation, with reversed columns values.

```
CLIENT_A | CLIENT_B
   02    |    01
   03    |    01
   05    |    01
   01    |    02
   01    |    03
   01    |    05
```

So I will need to check at PHP for both directions to find my client relations and to avoid duplicated entries.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This question is similar to yours. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/two-sided-unique-index-for-two-columns

Comment: You're doing it the right way. In maths terms, `A->B` does not imply the inverse. However, in your case it may do, in which case either store the relation both ways, or write your queries so it checks for both. In general, the former is faster than the latter, as queries are simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@halfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) said, a good way would be to check for the relation before you create it.

i.e.  when you'll try to insert a relationship, check if it doesn't exists already.

Yes, it`ll make your save slower, but grants your consistency.